# Is there a symmetry breaking model possible for mirror fermions in $E_8$?

Tags: gauge-theory, higgs, lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking, grand-unification

I've often been struck by how nicely the Standard model seems to fit into (supersymmetric) $E_8$. Specifically if we [write the root vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)) of $E_8$ as $(R,G,B,W,H,F,S,T)$. With colour being the complex vector $R+\omega G+\omega^2B$, electric charge being $Q=\frac{1}{6}(R+G+B-3W)$. Weak isospin with $\frac{1}{4}(W-H)$ and generation with $F+\omega  S+\omega^2 T$. i.e. splitting it as $SU(3)_c \times SU(2)_W\times SU(3)_F\times U(1)$. This assumes a flavour symmetry of $SU(3)$ which must be broken. The mirror fermions in this case would be those for which $FST= 1$ and normal ones where $FST=-1$. ($\omega$ being a complex cube root of unity).

The roots would take on $(\pm 1,\pm 1 ,\pm 1 ,\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ for the 128 Fermions (and 128 bosinos) with either an even or odd parity. And $(\pm 2,\mp 2,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ for the charged vector bosons (and sfermions). Even the Higgs fits somewhat nicely in the scheme if we have it with roots such as $(0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2)$ which accounts for flavour mixing. (Perhaps the Higgs particles also have a $E_8$ representation). In interactions these charges add together.

However there are some things wrong with it. Firstly there would be 4 families and 4 mirror-families of fermions accounting for the 8 of $SU(3)_F$. So it might be said that there are 'too many unobserved particles'.

But the main problem is how to break the symmetry, so that all these particles become super-massive:

- 1 generation of 'normal' 16 fermions
- 4 generations of mirror fermions (64 fermions).
- 108 bosons (120 - 12 standard model bosons)
- 120 sfermions (super-partners of fermions)
- 128 bosinos (super-partners of bosons)
- Possibly up to 240 more Higgs particles of various charges.

That's over 500 particles to be made super-massive! It's like the Standard model might just be the tip of an iceberg and the other 90% is out of reach. But to me that sounds like what we should expect. (Why should all the particles be super light after all)

Are there any no-go theorems that say that Higgs can't break the symmetry and give all these particles huge masses? For example, is it impossible for a Higgs mechanism to give all the mirror fermions big masses while keeping the standard model fermions low masses? I wonder how many Higgs particles you would actually need to break the symmetry.

Comment: There's a standard no-go theorem for this kind of GUT, which is that $E_8$ doesn't have any complex representations, so you automatically end up with unwanted mirror matter upon generic symmetry breaking. (Specifically, either you have unwanted light particles, or the particles you want end up GUT-scale heavy.) Of course, you can just say that there is some tuning which makes precisely the particles of the SM the light ones, and everything else heavy, but then all the "beauty" of the scheme is lost...

Comment: @knzhou So do you mean, that with precise tuning one can make it work? Perhaps we just live in a very unlikely Unverse! Or is it simply impossible to get rid of those mirror particles? If we could make it work with fine tuning, wouldn't this at least be a good model of nature with lots of nice symmetry?

Comment: I am reading this: https://cds.cern.ch/record/708018/files/0401212.pdf it seems like it talks about no-go theorems.